# The careers message "Report" button does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I tried to report recruiter spam on Stack Overflow Jobs, but the button doesn't do anything. The Firefox console prints the following error every time I click:

```
Error: $(...).modal is not a function
8853/</e.report@https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1:358296
fn@https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8 line 1 > Function:4:209
n@https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1:111577
i@https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1:149749
$eval@https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1:120704
$apply@https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1:120939
compile/</<@https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1:149800
dispatch@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:12444
add/r.handle@https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js:3:9173
b@https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/trackjs/3.7.3/t.min.js?v=074c380714bf:4:462
t.min.js:13:405
    e https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/trackjs/3.7.3/t.min.js?v=074c380714bf:13
    o https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1
    get https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1
    $apply https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1
    compile https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Ts/EntryPoints/messages.js?v=b26cf755b5e8:1
    jQuery 2
    b https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/Js/third-party/trackjs/3.7.3/t.min.js?v=074c380714bf:4
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this! The JS to render the dialog had gone missing from the page. Should be fixed now.